# ARM Tempate Fails to Export Keys When Account Name Has a Dash

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have an arm template to deploy a documentdb.  If i use a dash in the name the document database deploys, but my output params fail; however if I use no dashes in the name output params succeed.

Given a CosmosDbAccountName of accountnamedev, database deploys and keys / endpoint export just fine.

Given a CosmosDbAccountName of accountname-dev, database deploys, but keys fail to export with:

> 1:41:56 PM - Resource Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts 'accountname-dev' failed with message '{
>     "code": "NotFound",
>     "message": "Request url is invalid.\r\nActivityId: c048e914-ccba-4be1-a38f-0d8bb89020bf, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.1.0.0"
>   }'

I've found no real descriptions about this being a problem, so I feel like I'm missing something simple, I'm definitely not an ARM expert.

```
    {
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "CosmosDbAccountName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "CosmosDbConsistencyLevel" : {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "CosmosDbConsistencyPolicyMaxIntervalInSeconds" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "CosmosDbConsistencyPolicyMaxStalenessPrefix" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "Location": {
        "type": "string"
      }
  },
  "variables": {
    "documentDb" : {
      "name" : "[parameters('CosmosDbAccountName')]",
      "databaseAccountOfferType" : "Standard",
      "consistencyPolicy" : {
        "defaultConsistencyLevel": "[parameters('CosmosDbConsistencyLevel')]",
        "maxIntervalInSeconds": "[parameters('CosmosDbConsistencyPolicyMaxIntervalInSeconds')]",
        "maxStalenessPrefix": "[parameters('CosmosDbConsistencyPolicyMaxStalenessPrefix')]"
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
      "kind": "GlobalDocumentDB",
      "name": "[variables('documentDb').name]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-04-08",
      "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
      "properties": {
          "databaseAccountOfferType": "[variables('documentDb').databaseAccountOfferType]",
          "consistencyPolicy": "[variables('documentDb').consistencyPolicy]",
          "locations":[
            {
              "locationName": "[parameters('Location')]",
              "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
              "failoverPriority": 0
            }
          ],
          "capabilities":[]
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "endPoint": {
      "type": "string",
      "value":"[concat('https://', variables('documentDb').name, '.documents.azure.com:443/')]"
    },
    "primaryKey": {
      "type":"string",
      "value":"[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('documentDb').name), providers('Microsoft.DocumentDB','databaseAccounts').apiVersions[0]).primaryMasterKey]"
    },
    "instanceName": {
      "type":"string",
      "value":"variables('documentDb').name"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you try using latest api version? seems it is `2016-03-31` as of now

Comment: I tried the latest api version, same issue, I may just end up building a custom deployment task to pull out the keys via the list keys docdb rest resource.

Comment: If I run this template through azure deployemtn, instead of an azure-devops pipeline, key and endpoint are output without issue.

Comment: I found this issue, it wasn't related to the template at all, when I fixed that this worked fine even under the older api-version.

Comment: what was it? :)

Comment: I had an error higher up such that the account wasn't being deployed to the resource group I thought it was, so the error was (of course) correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case the error was due to the cosmosdb account not being deployed

Comment: Not being deployed to the resource group I expected it to be in.